# Using $ or the JQuery keyword in external JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Below is the content in my external js file.
Please i only have one function in my js file and i am calling this function 
from one of .cshtml file during onload event.

```
 function startJs()
 {

    $("#tabs").tabs();
    getImages();
    var imgCount = 0;
    var imgArray = new Array();
 }
```

Running this code i get the error saying "$ is not referenced". I get the same "not referenced error if i use the keyword JQuery.

I also tried declaring the function like this but still getting the same message.

```
$(function () {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

How can i make the Jquery symbols work in external js files. I feel that i am missing something very simple here but i just can't figure out what i am missing.
Please note i am making a call to this code from a file that has a reference to Jquery.

Anybody has any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you including this file **after** you include jQuery?

Comment: You should add this script after you have added jQuery to your page

Comment: Hi Both.   The file was called from .cshtml file which had reference to jquery. i did add this script after referencing jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML should look like this, **note the order** of the JS files:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="yourCustomFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ideally those should be before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thats not on HTML file. The script i have displayed are put in an external javascript file called  selfInro.Js

Comment: @Sike12 Yes but your HTML file will dictate if jQuery will work on your file or not. jQuery has to be initialized before your file otherwise your file does not know what `jQuery` or `$` are

Comment: I have jQuery referenced in my .cshtml file that calls this external js file may be i should make a direct reference to jquery from the external js file

Comment: @Sike12 Can you edit your question and post the content of your `.cshtml` file?

Comment: Hi @StackErr. I figured out that i was relying on the bundling and minification system to reference the jquery. However putting the reference script right in .cshtml file solved the issue. I'll have to figure out how can i acheive this from the Bundling system. I'll mark your answer as the chosen one as your comment helped me fix it. Thanks